# How to change the local directory of Subversion in WebStorm / PhpStorm / IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I've installed the SVN Toolbar plugin in PhpStorm.

This is my project's folder structure (psudo):

```
\Project Root

    \folder1

    \folder2

    \www

        \folder3

        \folder4

        \server
```

And at first, I used checkout to set the folder `server` as the local destination folder for SVN. It works fine.

Now I need to change local folder to another one, i.e. `www`. But I don't know how to do it.

No matter what I did, it always took `server` as the local destination folder.

And in the left side project structure pane in PhpStorm, only folder `server` has a 'Subversion' menu item in the right click menu. How can I make folder `www` instead of folder `server` to have this 'Subversion' menu item?

Comment: You should checkout `www` so that it's your new working copy (it will have `.svn` subdirectory). Then you'll be able to use IDE SVN integration features with this directory.

Comment: Thank you! But I have checkout `www` and I can synchronize it in Desktop or Windows Explorer normally. And there is a `.svn` subdirectory in `www` folder, while there is no `.svn` in `server` now (I've deleted it). But in PhpStorm, the situation still remains the same - update will pull all the remote `www` content into local `server` folder, and only `server` folder has the `Subversion` right-click menu item.

Comment: Remove `server` mapping in Settings | Version Control and add a new mapping for `www` instead.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I really should do. My problem was solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `server` mapping in `Settings` (`Preferences` on Mac) | `Version Control` and add a new mapping for the `www` directory instead.

[Check the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/associating-a-directory-with-a-specific-version-control-system.html) for the details.

Comment: Yes, it does work! It solves my problem perfectly. Thank you so much!